# Вопрос по ОпенКарт. Помогите пожалуйста(

Tags: opencart

Здравствуйте.
Помогите пожалуйста мне с ОпенКарт.
1) Внизу сайта есть графа для товаров и для инстаграмма. Так было изначально, когда я купил шаблон. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я могу подключить эти модули? А именно, почему при добавлении товаров, на главную они не скидываются, видимо их нужно как-то помечать. Как можно узнать как и как добавлять некоторые товары сюда?
Модуль инстаграмма при открытии спрашивает КлиентИд какой-то. Откуда его взять и как можно настроить этот модуль? В идеале, чтобы фото из инстаграмма там постились тоже, ну или хотя бы как-то был виден аккаунт инстаграмма и хотя-бы некоторые фото. Вот скрин настроек :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2) На скрине обозначит стрелочкой на цену. Как я могу сделать во первых отступ названия товара от цены больше, во вторых увеличить текст с ценой, а в третьих изменить цвет надписи цены на бордовый какой-нибудь? Надеюсь понятно описал. Чтобы вот название товара, потом был больший отступ, а ниже уже цена.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3) Понимаю, что вопросы тупые и возможно вы меня захейтите даже, но пожалуйста помогите, направьте, напишите... Сроки поджимают, а сам я чего-то растерялся)

Comment: не знаю как поднять тему. Если так нельзя - то извиняюсь)

Comment: Пункт 2 более не актуален, а остальные вопросы не знаю как решить((

Comment: остался только первый вопрос...

Comment: Я так понимаю шаблон от ТМ? Вот инструкция по модулю инстаграм от них [https://www.templatemonster.com/help/ru/opencart-2-x-how-to-manage-tm-instagram-module.html](https://www.templatemonster.com/help/ru/opencart-2-x-how-to-manage-tm-instagram-module.html)

Comment: @AndrewHobbit, да, спасибо, инст настроил:)
теперь я только не понимаю, как добавляются товары на главную, что нужно указать в товаре, чтобы он попал на главную)

Comment: Это не в товарах указывается, а в каком-то из модулей. Тоже надо в документации к шаблону смотреть. Посмотрите в схеме главной страницы какие модули выводятся и смотрите их настройки.